# How can I get the ID of parent's taxonomy in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

I need to get the parent's taxonomy ID by the sub taxonomy's name.

E.g.:

```
Italy   - parent
Livingo - sub
```

On the `Livingo` page, I need to be able to get `Italy`'s ID.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$subCategory = get_term_by( 'slug', get_query_var( 'term' ), $current_taxonomy );
$mainCategory = get_term_by( 'id', $subCategory->parent, $current_taxonomy );
```

After that, `$mainCategory` will be an array with all details about that term (slug, name, parent etc).

Comment: Tnx a lot. If there a function to filter, with sublevel it is? For example this function i need only on 3 sublevel.

Comment: you can make a recursive function to check the parent id. If that is zero, you have the top parent. Check terms which have parent id as the top parent and you get level one child, do the check again for the level one elements and you get level two, and so on. Be careful though, this may lead to some performance issues, especially if you have a large amount of children and/or deep nesting. But this wont be visible unless you have a large number of visitors.